# MYSQL query to return dates for which a car is available to be booked

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get dates from the table for which a car is available and there is no existing booking for the car in a specific DATE RANGE.

[image: Table]

LIKE if car is booked for 2017-05-20 to 2017-05-25 , MY date range 2017-05-01 to 2017-05-30. It should return 2017-05-01 to 2017-05-19 and 2017-05-26 to 2017-05-30.

I am trying:

```
SELECT 
    car_id, ADDDATE(to_date, 1) AS date
FROM
    car_bookings
WHERE
    car_id = 42 AND
    from_date >= '2017-04-01' AND
    to_date <= '2017-04-31' 
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        car_id, SUBDATE(from_date, 1) AS date
    FROM
        car_bookings
    WHERE
        from_date >= '2017-04-01' AND
        to_date <= '2017-04-31' AND
        from_date NOT IN (
            SELECT 
                MIN(from_date)
            FROM
                car_bookings
            WHERE
                car_id = 42 AND
                from_date >= '2017-04-01' AND
                to_date <= '2017-04-31'
        ) AND
        car_id = 42 AND
        from_date >= '2017-04-01' AND
        to_date <= '2017-04-31'
)      
ORDER BY date
```

Please ask if more information is required.

Comment: What is your SQL query?

Comment: select car_id, adddate(to_date,1) as date from car_bookings where car_id=42 and from_date >= '2017-04-01' and to_date <= '2017-04-31' UNION 
(select car_id,subdate(from_date,1) as date from car_bookings where from_date >= '2017-04-01' and to_date <= '2017-04-31' and from_date not in (select min(from_date) from car_bookings where car_id=42 and from_date >= '2017-04-01' and to_date <= '2017-04-31') and car_id=42 and from_date >= '2017-04-01' and to_date <= '2017-04-31') order by date